# d3 heatmap chart draw data based on a filter

Tags: d3.js

I am referring [this](http://bl.ocks.org/ganezasan/dfe585847d65d0742ca7d0d1913d50e1) to draw a chart. I want to draw a month vs time of the day chart.From what I infer from this link is that it draws data like in a matrix format (1,1),(1,2) ... What I want is to show Jan Feb ... Dec on x axis and 0:00,1:00 .... 24:00 on y axis. I have a month filter so an user can select from Mar to Jun if he wants to. How can I modify this code to suit my needs?

```
const margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
          width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
          gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24),
          legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
          buckets = 9,
          colors = ["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"], // alternatively colorbrewer.YlGnBu[9]
          days = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],
          times = ["1a", "2a", "3a", "4a", "5a", "6a", "7a", "8a", "9a", "10a", "11a", "12a", "1p", "2p", "3p", "4p", "5p", "6p", "7p", "8p", "9p", "10p", "11p", "12p"];
          datasets = ["data.tsv", "data2.tsv"];

      const svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      const dayLabels = svg.selectAll(".dayLabel")
          .data(days)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text(function (d) { return d; })
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", (d, i) => i * gridSize)
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize / 1.5 + ")")
            .attr("class", (d, i) => ((i >= 0 && i <= 4) ? "dayLabel mono axis axis-workweek" : "dayLabel mono axis"));

      const timeLabels = svg.selectAll(".timeLabel")
          .data(times)
          .enter().append("text")
            .text((d) => d)
            .attr("x", (d, i) => i * gridSize)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize / 2 + ", -6)")
            .attr("class", (d, i) => ((i >= 7 && i <= 16) ? "timeLabel mono axis axis-worktime" : "timeLabel mono axis"));

      const type = (d) => {
        return {
          day: +d.day,
          hour: +d.hour,
          value: +d.value
        };
      };

      const heatmapChart = function(tsvFile) {
        d3.tsv(tsvFile, type, (error, data) => {
          const colorScale = d3.scaleQuantile()
            .domain([0, buckets - 1, d3.max(data, (d) => d.value)])
            .range(colors);

          const cards = svg.selectAll(".hour")
              .data(data, (d) => d.day+':'+d.hour);

          cards.append("title");

          cards.enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", (d) => (d.hour - 1) * gridSize)
              .attr("y", (d) => (d.day - 1) * gridSize)
              .attr("rx", 4)
              .attr("ry", 4)
              .attr("class", "hour bordered")
              .attr("width", gridSize)
              .attr("height", gridSize)
              .style("fill", colors[0])
            .merge(cards)
              .transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .style("fill", (d) => colorScale(d.value));

          cards.select("title").text((d) => d.value);

          cards.exit().remove();

          const legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
              .data([0].concat(colorScale.quantiles()), (d) => d);

          const legend_g = legend.enter().append("g")
              .attr("class", "legend");

          legend_g.append("rect")
            .attr("x", (d, i) => legendElementWidth * i)
            .attr("y", height)
            .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
            .attr("height", gridSize / 2)
            .style("fill", (d, i) => colors[i]);

          legend_g.append("text")
            .attr("class", "mono")
            .text((d) => "≥ " + Math.round(d))
            .attr("x", (d, i) => legendElementWidth * i)
            .attr("y", height + gridSize);

          legend.exit().remove();
        });
      };

      heatmapChart(datasets[0]);

      const datasetpicker = d3.select("#dataset-picker")
        .selectAll(".dataset-button")
        .data(datasets);

      datasetpicker.enter()
        .append("input")
        .attr("value", (d) => "Dataset " + d)
        .attr("type", "button")
        .attr("class", "dataset-button")
        .on("click", (d) => heatmapChart(d));
```